# How to "program to an interface"

Tags: design, object-oriented, language-agnostic, interfaces, design-principles

I've read these questions:

- [Understanding "programming to an interface"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/232359/95744)
- [What is the point of an interface?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/131332/95744)
- [Does it always make sense to "program to an interface" in Java?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/283762/95744)

I don't understand how to "program to an interface" if you are using methods in concrete classes that aren't part of the interface.

I realize the most common example of this design principle is the `List` vs `ArrayList` in Java because it is easy to understand and illustrate the point.

Here is a somewhat silly example to illustrate what my question is asking (the code is in PHP but it applies to most OOP languages):

```php
interface ResponseInterface {
    public function getStatusCode();
}

class Response implements ResponseInterface {
    private $status;

    public function getStatusCode() {
        return $this->status;
    }
}

class AwesomeResponse implements ResponseInterface {
    private $status;
    private $message = ['200' => 'OK', '500' => 'Internal Server Error'];

    public function getStatusCode() {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function getStatusMessage() {
        return $this->message[$status];
    }
}

class Server {
    public function sendResponse(ResponseInterface $response) {
        // this seems wrong -----^

        header(vsprintf('HTTP/1.1 %d %s', [
            $response->getStatusCode(),
            $response->getStatusMessage()
        ]), true, $response->getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `sendResponse` method takes a `ResponseInterface` parameter but it calls `getStatusMessage()` which isn't part of the interface but only something implemented in `AwesomeResponse`, which implements `ResponseInterface`.

The application crashes at runtime when a `Response` object is passed as it tries to call the non-existent method `getStatusMessage()`. Therefore, the proper implementation would be:

```php
public function sendResponse(AwesomeResponse $response) {
    // ...stuff
}
```

But `AwesomeResponse` isn't an interface so how do I program to an interface?

Comment: Quick answer: you cannot always program to an interface if you rely on implementation details such as this. Java should ideally have a `RandomAccessList` interface that is a subinterface of `List` and `RandomAccess` and contains signatures of the methods on `ArrayList` that are not on any interface.

Comment: Well if you're programming to the interface `ResponseInterface`, and `ResponseInterface` has no status messages, then **there is no such thing as a status message as far as you are concerned**.

Comment: (So your options are to add `getStatusMessage` to `ResponseInterface`, or to stop pretending that your code works with any object that implements `ResponseInterface` (i.e. stop "programming to that interface"))

Comment: If you want to follow this principle religiously, your IDE should make it painless. IntelliJ-IDEA supports "extract interface" refactoring which also finds and replaces occurrences of concrete variables with their corresponding interface declaration. Also, I'm sure you can find an analyzer in IntelliJ which will automatically find all non-library places where you declare concrete variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm - a less trivial example might help.  Consider [Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html), which is an interface that defines a contract for executing `Runnables`.

Now, if you write `AwesomeService` like this:

```
class AwesomeService {
    // ...
    public void runAllPendingTasks(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
        for(Runnable task : pendingTasks) {
            executor.execute(task);
        }
    }
 }
```

Then my code, trying to call yours, needs to find a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor lying around somewhere.  On the other hand, if your method signature admits that your needs can be satisfied by anything that implements Executor

```
class AwesomeService {
    // ...
    public void runAllPendingTasks(Executor executor) {
        for(Runnable task : pendingTasks) {
            executor.execute(task);
        }
    }
 }
```

The my code can pass you my customized `Executor`, and there by enhance what actually happens when you run your tasks.  For instance, I might want to track how often we run tasks, so that I can generate metrics in real time that monitor the health of the application.

```
class MeteredExecutor implements Executor {
    private final Executor impl;
    private final io.dropwizard.metrics.Meter meter;

    MeteredExecutor(...) {...}

    public void execute(Runnable command) {
        meter.mark();
        impl.execute(command);
    }
}
```

OK, so why doesn't an interface seem to help for `AwesomeResponse`?  The primary answer is encapsulation -- the `MeteredExecutor` provides the execute service by using its own internal state to satisfy a request.  What it doesn't do is share that internal state.  Notice that `AwesomeService` calls execute, and lets the `MeteredExecutor` do the work, rather than calling `getMeter().mark()` and `getImpl.execute(command)`.

"Give me your internal state" is a really lousy motivation for an interface.

`AwesomeResponse` is exposing its data.  That's not necessarily a bad thing; in your example as written, AwesomeResponse is essentially a representation of a message that is about to cross an application boundary.  Put another way, it's a value type that makes up part of the api of your Service; of course it exposes its data, that's what it is for!

Calling out the same point a different way: notice that in the case of AwesomeService and the interfaces, state is being passed inwards.  My state is an executor, and I pass that to AwesomeService.  The state of AwesomeService is a task, an it passes that task to the Executor, which in turn passes it inward to another Executor, and turtles all the way down.  Interfaces work great for this.

On the other hand, in AwesomeResponse, the state is coming out.  Writing interfaces to fetch the state out is just extra work.

BUT

Encapsulation is a good thing, and AwesomeResponse isn't quite at the application boundary.  Could we rewrite things so that state is passed inward?

```
interface Writer {
    void header(int code, String message);
}

interface Response {
    void writeTo(Writer writer);
}

class AwesomeResponse implements Response {
    void writeTo(Writer writer) {
        writer.header(this.code, this.message);
    }
}

class NotSoAwesomeResponse implements Response {
    void writeTo(Writer writer) {
        writer.header(this.code, String.valueOf(this.code));
    }
}

class ServerWriter implements Writer {
    void header(int code, String message) {
        header(vsprintf('HTTP/1.1 %d %s', [
            code,
            message
        ]), true, code);
    }
}

class Server {
    public function sendResponse(Response response) {
        ServerWriter writer = new ServerWriter();
        response.writeTo(writer);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there might be some typos and missing instance fields in this code example....

Answer (score 8):

That is the point. If you depend on concrete details of the class, you are not coding to an interface by definition.

This means you cannot drop out those implementation details and replace them with others. Since change is inevitable in business, this is going to cause you problems down the road. You will need to add that capability to the interface (or make another interface for that other functionality) and work with that contract, not the details that you happen to be using now.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: this has nothing to do with *interfaces* which are defined by the keyword of the same name.

The advice means nothing else than **not to rely on a concrete implementation, rather on a well defined abstract behaviour**.

My knowlede of PHP is near 0 - so I apologize answering in a more general way.

Say you have an e-commerce application and domain-objects like `order`. Every `order` was created on some point in time. Oftentimes there are `filtering`operations to get a subset of orders within a given timeframe. You could write conditions like `order.getCreated() > concreteDate`. Besides other code smells, this is bad for another reason:
You tie your code to the implementation fact, that the `>` operation works with your code. If the implementation of the `date` is ever changed - say you use another `Date` object with other operators (e.g. `.after()`), your code is broken.

If you designed the `order` in a proper way, you would define the operation as `order.createdAfter(date)`, you define an `interface` aka. a well defined way to get information you need from an order, which is itself independed from the concrete implementation. The input is a `Date` and the result is a `boolean`.

It is allways good practice to choose the most abstract datatype for returnvalues to prevent assumptions (= dependencies) on concrete implementations. For example, it would be good practice in Java to return `Iterable<T>` instead of concrete `List` to prevent assuptions about the behaviour of the resulting collection.

**tl;dr**

Read `interface` as *well defined behaviour* independent from concrete implementations.

Comment: Yes! Thinking that a Java `interface` is meant when talking about "programming to interfaces" is just wrong.

Comment: UP.  `createdAfter(date)` - on its *face* is excellent - [Alan Kay would give it a thumbs up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Kay). But that's about why we encapsulate, vice polymorphism. OTOH `Iterable<T>` is quite to point. Kay would say "it's all about the message". i.e. if there is a matching-signature method then the call (message) will be handled, period. He regrets coining *object oriented programming* because object type gets emphasis and strong typing restricts flexibility. SmallTalk, LISP, JavaScript, etc. coders look at us with pity.